# Reading Corona Data Error from URL with read.csv in R

Tags: r, url, read.csv

I used to read data from github with no problem and now I get error with the same simple code.

```
x <- getURL("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_time_series/time_series_covid19_confirmed_global.csv")
y <- read.csv(x, header = FALSE)
```

> Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection

In addition:

> Warning message: In file(file, "rt") : cannot open file 'HTTP/1.1 200
>   OK

Comment: I got the file OK but needed `read.csv(text=x)` instead (maybe the format has changed?)

Answer (score 1):

Use `data.table::fread`, it works I just checked

```r
data.table::fread("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_time_series/time_series_covid19_confirmed_global.csv")
```

works

Example:

```r
df <- data.table::fread("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_time_series/time_series_covid19_confirmed_global.csv")
df[,1:5]
 [0%] Downloaded 0 bytes...
                Province/State        Country/Region       Lat       Long 1/22/20
  1:                                     Afghanistan  33.00000  65.000000       0
  2:                                         Albania  41.15330  20.168300       0
  3:                                         Algeria  28.03390   1.659600       0
  4:                                         Andorra  42.50630   1.521800       0
  5:                                          Angola -11.20270  17.873900       0
 ---                                                                             
260: Saint Pierre and Miquelon                France  46.88520 -56.315900       0
261:                                     South Sudan   6.87700  31.307000       0
262:                                  Western Sahara  24.21550 -12.885800       0
263:                           Sao Tome and Principe   0.18636   6.613081       0
264:                                           Yemen  15.55273  48.516388       0
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the URL directly as file and set `header=TRUE`:

```
file <- "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_time_series/time_series_covid19_confirmed_global.csv"

y <- read.csv(file, header = TRUE)
```

Or use `read_delim` from package **readr**:

```
library("readr")
dat <- read_delim(file, delim=",")
```

The format of the covid data is not ideal for further analysis in R, but can easily be transformed with package **reshape2** or **dplyr**:

```
names(dat)[1:2] <- c("Province_State", "Country_Region")

library("dplyr")
dat2 <-
  dat %>%
  ## summarize Country/Region duplicates
  group_by(Country_Region) %>% summarise_at(vars(-(1:4)), sum) %>%
  ## make it a long table
  pivot_longer(cols = -Country_Region, names_to = "time") %>%
  ## convert to ISO 8601 date
  mutate(time = as.POSIXct(time, format="%m/%e/%y"))
```